# Automatic cell colouring using cellcolor: Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: color, tabularx, pgfmath, collcell

I am trying to produce a table, using `tabularx`, where the cells are coloured automatically depending upon their value.

I want to use the `\cellcolor` command as it will fill the whole cell, rather than `colorbox` command which seems to only fill the area around the numbers, and one has to fiddle with `\fboxsep` to get a suitable fill.

Here is a MWE, with the `Value 1` column coloured manually, the `Value 2` column should look the same, but there is an error in passing the numerical value to `\cellcolor`, which says I have an `Undefined Control Sequence`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}% openany
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{collcell}
\colorlet{LightSpringGreen}{white!70!lime}
\colorlet{LightRed}{white!70!red}
\newcommand{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand{\MaxNumber}{0}%
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}
    \cellcolor{LightSpringGreen!\PercentColor!LightRed}{#1}
}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}X<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\MinNumber}{0}%
\renewcommand{\MaxNumber}{1}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|l|H}
\hline
Name & Value 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 2} \\
\hline
a & \cellcolor{LightSpringGreen!20!LightRed}0.2 & 0.2\\
b & \cellcolor{LightSpringGreen!50!LightRed}0.5 & 0.5\\
c & \cellcolor{LightSpringGreen!60!LightRed}0.6 & 0.6\\
d & \cellcolor{LightSpringGreen!80!LightRed}0.8 & 0.8\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The problem appears to be associated with the way the number is passed. In a test run, if I put `\num{20}` in the 2nd column, 2nd row then the same error comes up.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: `cellcolor` is defined in the `colortbl` package, which you didn't load. I suspect  you loaded `collcell` for that, am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each table cell forms a group, so your definition of `\PercentColor` is lost by the time it reaches `\ApplyGradient`. If you make the definition `\global` (I've done so using `\global\edef` or, equivalently, `\xdef`) it works as expected:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{collcell}
\colorlet{LightSpringGreen}{white!70!lime}
\colorlet{LightRed}{white!70!red}
\newcommand{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand{\MaxNumber}{0}%
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}
  \xdef\PercentColor{\PercentColor}%
  \cellcolor{LightSpringGreen!\PercentColor!LightRed}{#1}
}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}X<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\MinNumber}{0}%
\renewcommand{\MaxNumber}{1}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|l|H}
\hline
Name & Value 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 2} \\
\hline
a & \cellcolor{LightSpringGreen!20!LightRed}0.2 & 0.2\\
b & \cellcolor{LightSpringGreen!50!LightRed}0.5 & 0.5\\
c & \cellcolor{LightSpringGreen!60!LightRed}0.6 & 0.6\\
d & \cellcolor{LightSpringGreen!80!LightRed}0.8 & 0.8\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```