# Automatic cell coloring with per-column minimum and maximum values

Tags: tables, color

I want to color each cell in a table based on its value. I know solutions exist, but you have to set the minimum and maximum values globally for the table. They can be found for example in [Are there an easy way to coloring tables depending on the value in each cell?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174998/are-there-an-easy-way-to-coloring-tables-depending-on-the-value-in-each-cell) and [Automatic cell colouring using cellcolor: Undefined Control Sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195698/automatic-cell-colouring-using-cellcolor-undefined-control-sequence).

I tried to come up with a solution that allows me to set the minimum and maximum values per column to be able to color each cell with their individual minimum and maximum values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xfp}
\definecolor{goodgreen}{HTML}{c5eecc}
\definecolor{goodred}{HTML}{ffc7ce}
\newcommand{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand{\MaxNumber}{1}%
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
  \cellcolor{goodgreen!\fpeval{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}!goodred}{#1}
}
\newcolumntype{H}[2]{>{\SetGradientLimits{#1}{#2}\collectcell\ApplyGradient}X<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\newcommand*{\SetGradientLimits}[2]{%
    \renewcommand*{\MinNumber}{#1}%
    \renewcommand*{\MaxNumber}{#2}%
}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|l|H{0}{1}|l|H{0}{100000}}
\hline
Name & Value 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 2} & Value 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 4} \\
\hline
a & \colorbox{goodgreen!20!goodred}{0.2} & 0.2 & \colorbox{goodgreen!20!goodred}{20000} & 20000\\
b & \colorbox{goodgreen!50!goodred}{0.5} & 0.5 & \colorbox{goodgreen!50!goodred}{50000} & 50000\\
c & \colorbox{goodgreen!60!goodred}{0.6} & 0.6 & \colorbox{goodgreen!60!goodred}{60000} & 60000\\
d & \colorbox{goodgreen!80!goodred}{0.8} & 0.8 & \colorbox{goodgreen!80!goodred}{80000} & 80000\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work correctly, since it seems to somehow calculate the mixture percentage before setting the values of `\MinNumber` and `\MaxNumber`. The error messages show that the calculation is done before:

```
Package color Error: Argument `-26.265' not in range [0,1].
Package color Error: Argument `25.83789' not in range [0,1].
Package color Error: Argument `-0.47716' not in range [0,1].
```

[image: Wrong solution with cell color]

If I replace the `\cellcolor` command by `\colorbox` in the `\ApplyGradient` macro, it works. But I would like the whole cell to be colored, just like the `\cellcolor` command does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xfp}
\definecolor{goodgreen}{HTML}{c5eecc}
\definecolor{goodred}{HTML}{ffc7ce}
\newcommand{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand{\MaxNumber}{0}%
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
  \colorbox{goodgreen!\fpeval{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}!goodred}{#1}
}
\newcolumntype{H}[2]{>{\SetGradientLimits{#1}{#2}\collectcell\ApplyGradient}X<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\newcommand*{\SetGradientLimits}[2]{%
    \renewcommand*{\MinNumber}{#1}%
    \renewcommand*{\MaxNumber}{#2}%
}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|l|H{0}{1}|l|H{0}{100000}}
\hline
Name & Value 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 2} & Value 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 4} \\
\hline
a & \colorbox{goodgreen!20!goodred}{0.2} & 0.2 & \colorbox{goodgreen!20!goodred}{20000} & 20000\\
b & \colorbox{goodgreen!50!goodred}{0.5} & 0.5 & \colorbox{goodgreen!50!goodred}{50000} & 50000\\
c & \colorbox{goodgreen!60!goodred}{0.6} & 0.6 & \colorbox{goodgreen!60!goodred}{60000} & 60000\\
d & \colorbox{goodgreen!80!goodred}{0.8} & 0.8 & \colorbox{goodgreen!80!goodred}{80000} & 80000\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Working solution with colorbox]

Is that possible?

**UPDATE**

I deliberately chose to use the `xfp` package for calculations, because I want to bypass the `Dimensions too large` limitation of doing calculations in `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

---

## Bypass to the limitation of `Dimensions too large` in `pgfplots`

---

### UPDATE 3 - with `xfp` package

#### --> *data range: ± 10^10000*

The original question was about a solution with the `xfp` package, because of this I have still been looking for an approach until I found it. Thus, I have redefined the `\Percent` macro as:

```
\newcommand\Percent{\fpeval{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}}
```

in the `\ApplyGradient` one:

```
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
    \newcommand\Percent{\fpeval{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{\Percent}
    \xdef\PercentColor{\PercentColor}%
    \cellcolor{goodgreen!\PercentColor!goodred}{#1}
}
```

And that´s it. Anyhow, I thought I had tried such as simple solution before and in the same way, but I did not succeed ...

Output (same as with the other approaches):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xfp}

\definecolor{goodgreen}{HTML}{c5eecc}
\definecolor{goodred}{HTML}{ffc7ce}
\newcommand{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand{\MaxNumber}{0}%


\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
    \newcommand\Percent{\fpeval{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{\Percent}
    \xdef\PercentColor{\PercentColor}%
    \cellcolor{goodgreen!\PercentColor!goodred}{#1}
}


\newcolumntype{H}[2]{>{\SetGradientLimits{#1}{#2}\collectcell\ApplyGradient}X<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \newcommand*{\SetGradientLimits}[2]{%
            \renewcommand*{\MinNumber}{#1}%
            \renewcommand*{\MaxNumber}{#2}%
        }

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|l|H{0}{1}|l|H{0}{100000}}
            \hline
            Name & Value 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 2} & Value 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 4} \\
            \hline
            a & \cellcolor{goodgreen!20!goodred}0.2 & 0.2 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!20!goodred}20000 & 20000\\
            b & \cellcolor{goodgreen!50!goodred}0.5 & 0.5 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!50!goodred}50000 & 50000\\
            c & \cellcolor{goodgreen!60!goodred}0.6 & 0.6 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!60!goodred}60000 & 60000\\
            d & \cellcolor{goodgreen!80!goodred}0.8 & 0.8 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!80!goodred}80000 & 80000\\
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

### UPDATE 2 - with `fpu` library (`pfg/tikz`)

#### --> *data range: ± 10^324*  (at least the IEEE double precision data range)

[schtandard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/48973/schtandard)´s comment:

> `pgf` also has a library called `fpu` that enables you to use numbers up to `10^{324}`. (See section 56 of the manual.)

has given me a clue to overcome the limitation (*numbers up to `±9.99910^{17}`*) of the `fp` package (thanks for this hint). For this reason, I have tried to implement the `fpu` `tikzlibrary` in my code. Therefore, I have added:

```
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
```

to the preamble. Furthermore, I have redefined the `\Applygradient` macro once again :

```
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}
    \xdef\Percent{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{\Percent}
    \xdef\PercentColor{\PercentColor}%
    \cellcolor{goodgreen!\PercentColor!goodred}{#1}
}
```

and thus I have obtained the same desired output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{collcell}

\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}

\definecolor{goodgreen}{HTML}{c5eecc}
\definecolor{goodred}{HTML}{ffc7ce}
\newcommand{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand{\MaxNumber}{0}%

\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}
    \xdef\Percent{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{\Percent}
    \xdef\PercentColor{\PercentColor}%
    \cellcolor{goodgreen!\PercentColor!goodred}{#1}
}


\newcolumntype{H}[2]{>{\SetGradientLimits{#1}{#2}\collectcell\ApplyGradient}X<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\newcommand*{\SetGradientLimits}[2]{%
    \renewcommand*{\MinNumber}{#1}%
    \renewcommand*{\MaxNumber}{#2}%
}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|l|H{0}{1}|l|H{0}{100000}}

\hline
Name & Value 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 2} & Value 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 4} \\
\hline
a & \cellcolor{goodgreen!20!goodred}0.2 & 0.2 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!20!goodred}20000 & 20000\\
b & \cellcolor{goodgreen!50!goodred}0.5 & 0.5 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!50!goodred}50000 & 50000\\
c & \cellcolor{goodgreen!60!goodred}0.6 & 0.6 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!60!goodred}60000 & 60000\\
d & \cellcolor{goodgreen!80!goodred}0.8 & 0.8 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!80!goodred}80000 & 80000\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### UPDATE 1 - with `fp` package

#### --> *data range: ± 9.99910^17*

I have found an approach using `\cellcolor` with the macro `\FPeval` of the `fp` package instead of `\colorbox` with the macro `\fpeval` of the `xfp` package (I hope this is not a problem for you). Therefore, I have redefined the macro `\Applygradient` from the solution to [Automatic cell colouring using cellcolor: Undefined Control Sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195701/89320) by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner):

```
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
  \FPeval{\Percent}{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{\Percent}
  \xdef\PercentColor{\PercentColor}%
  \cellcolor{goodgreen!\PercentColor!goodred}{#1}
}
```

This compiles correctly and it is possible to obtain your desired output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{fp}

\definecolor{goodgreen}{HTML}{c5eecc}
\definecolor{goodred}{HTML}{ffc7ce}
\newcommand{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand{\MaxNumber}{0}%


\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
  \FPeval{\Percent}{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{\Percent}
  \xdef\PercentColor{\PercentColor}%
  \cellcolor{goodgreen!\PercentColor!goodred}{#1}
}


\newcolumntype{H}[2]{>{\SetGradientLimits{#1}{#2}\collectcell\ApplyGradient}X<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\newcommand*{\SetGradientLimits}[2]{%
    \renewcommand*{\MinNumber}{#1}%
    \renewcommand*{\MaxNumber}{#2}%
}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|l|H{0}{1}|l|H{0}{100000}}

\hline
Name & Value 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 2} & Value 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 4} \\
\hline
a & \cellcolor{goodgreen!20!goodred}0.2 & 0.2 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!20!goodred}20000 & 20000\\
b & \cellcolor{goodgreen!50!goodred}0.5 & 0.5 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!50!goodred}50000 & 50000\\
c & \cellcolor{goodgreen!60!goodred}0.6 & 0.6 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!60!goodred}60000 & 60000\\
d & \cellcolor{goodgreen!80!goodred}0.8 & 0.8 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!80!goodred}80000 & 80000\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Limitation

In the documentation of the `fp` package states:

> Fixed point arithmetic for TEX with numbers ranging from −999999999999999999.999999999999999999 to +999999999999999999.999999999999999999

---

## With the limitation of `Dimensions too large` in `pgfplots`

---

#### --> *data range: ± 16384*

Just replacing `\colorbox` with `\cellcolor` in `tabularx` to your working solution and taking the original definition of `\Applygradient` from the solution to [Automatic cell colouring using cellcolor: Undefined Control Sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195701/89320) by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner):

```
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}
    \xdef\PercentColor{\PercentColor}%
    \cellcolor{goodgreen!\PercentColor!goodred}{#1}
}
```

you obtain your desired output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xfp}

\definecolor{goodgreen}{HTML}{c5eecc}
\definecolor{goodred}{HTML}{ffc7ce}
\newcommand{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand{\MaxNumber}{0}%


\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}
    \xdef\PercentColor{\PercentColor}%
    \cellcolor{goodgreen!\PercentColor!goodred}{#1}
}


\newcolumntype{H}[2]{>{\SetGradientLimits{#1}{#2}\collectcell\ApplyGradient}X<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \newcommand*{\SetGradientLimits}[2]{%
            \renewcommand*{\MinNumber}{#1}%
            \renewcommand*{\MaxNumber}{#2}%
        }

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|l|H{0}{1}|l|H{0}{100}}
            \hline
            Name & Value 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 2} & Value 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value 4} \\
            \hline
            a & \cellcolor{goodgreen!20!goodred}0.2 & 0.2 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!20!goodred}20 & 20\\
            b & \cellcolor{goodgreen!50!goodred}0.5 & 0.5 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!50!goodred}50 & 50\\
            c & \cellcolor{goodgreen!60!goodred}0.6 & 0.6 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!60!goodred}60 & 60\\
            d & \cellcolor{goodgreen!80!goodred}0.8 & 0.8 & \cellcolor{goodgreen!80!goodred}80 & 80\\
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but unfortunately it only works for numbers smaller than 16384 because of the calculations are done in dimensions. I forgot to add to my question that it also needs to support larger numbers. That is why I chose to use the `xfp` package. I'll update the question.

Comment: `pgf` also has a library called `fpu` that enables you to use numbers up to `10^{324}`. (See section 56 of the manual.)

Comment: @schtandard, thanks for the hint  +1, :) I have found an approach with the `fpu` library, see my answer.

Comment: Very nice answer. Now to the bonus question: why does it work this way, but not using the `xfp` macro directly inside the color calculation?

Comment: @jessepeng,  I think the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195701/89320) to this question has already been given by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner). 

_Each table cell forms a group, so your addition of  `\fpeval` is lost by the time it reaches `\ApplyGradient`. If you make the definition `\global` (I've done so using `\global\edef` or, equivalently, `\xdef`) it works as expected_